# Adjective for someone who makes things work in spite of few resources

Tags: adjectives

I was looking for a word that describes someone who can make do with very little, someone who achieves small practical goals in spite of inconvenience, instead of just giving up on those small goals. Something similar to handy, crafty, pragmatic, but not relating to perseverance, motivation or stemina. This seems like a very defined characteristic to me and I don't know yet how to refer to it.

Comment: "To MacGuyver something" is now considered to be a transitive verb (informal and not an adjective), but it is defined by the resourceful action of using this talent. It may not be useful, but I thought I would offer it.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned (lack of) resources, so the first thing that comes to mind is:

> ***[resourceful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resourceful)***
>   Having the ability to find quick and clever ways to overcome difficulties.
>   *‘he maintained her reputation for being a resourceful problem-solver’*
>   *‘you will become stronger and more resourceful in the face of adversity’*

Answer (score 0):

How about "capable"?

You can also browse something like [an online thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com)